# Changing views after sending an email

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm having trouble thinking of ways to change views after hitting "send" when in email mode. I have a main view that is a form that the user fills out, that info then populates the email. Now when I hit "send" I don't want the user to go back to the form page but a new one.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your view controller interface.

then make the current view controller the delegate when initializing the ``

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

**you will be notified of the status of the mail in the method**

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
//          message.text = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                      break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSent:

            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *FailedAlert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Mail could not be sent" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [FailedAlert show];
            [FailedAlert release];  
            break;
        }
        default:
            NSLog(@"Hit default case in the switch");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

Here you should be able to load a new view based on your choice and result.